# Does jekyll support @use sass statement?

Tags: css, sass, jekyll

According to [sass](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/import) the `@import` statement is directed to deprecation, in favour of `@use`, yet in the jekyll docs there are only examples of the first kind... I however can't get the latter to work!

When I try to reference a variable from a partial `_color.sass`:

```
$duck-blue: #199
```

With the use statement in some other partial `_nav.sass`:

```
@use 'color'

.duckdiv: 
    border: 2px solid color.$duck-blue
```

Jekyll throws the following

```
Error: Invalid CSS after "...2px solid color": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was ".$duck-blue; }"
```

While everything works if I replace `@use` by `@import` and remove the `color.` scope in front of the variable.

Is there something I'm getting wrong?

Comment: `@use` must be above all others definitions, including variables (cfr. https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/use): I can’t see issues here, if both Jekyll and Sass are up-to-date. Try with `border: 2px solid + color.$duck-blue`. But with `@import` you have to remove the dot notation before your variable… as you noticed, otherwise it’s just `$duck-blue`, not `color.$duck-blue`.

Comment: Here is what I get with bundle info: jekyll 4.0.0, jekyll-sass-converter 2.1.0, sassc 2.3.0. Still fails with `color: (+) color.$duck-blue` and @use on top of the file...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into this myself and spent a while digging, here's what I found.

Jekyll uses LibSass converter to convert SCSS to CSS.  Lybsass has been deprecated now for over a year.  The new modern converter is [Dart Sass](https://sass-lang.com/dart-sass) which includes the new @use references.

There is an open ticket in Jekyll to use dart-sass: https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-sass-converter/issues/116

But in the meantime you can change the default sass converter by hand with a new gem: https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-sass-converter/issues/116#issuecomment-850912425

Comment: Also if you are experimenting the issue with GitHub page, that's because it is using an old version of the jekyll-sass-converter. https://github.com/github/pages-gem/issues/813